# package creating errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to build a package that will allow me to insert grades in a table. The teachers have some certain classes that they teach and I want to raise a exception when a teacher wants to put a grade to a class that they don't teach.
This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE manager_facultate IS
     PROCEDURE inserare_nota (nr_matr studenti.nr_matricol%type, nume profesori.nume%type, id_curs note.id_curs%type, valoarea note.valoare%type);
END manager_facultate;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY manager_facultate IS

    FUNCTION returneaza_id_curs (id_curs NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        CURSOR c1 (nume) IS
           SELECT d.id_curs from didactic d JOIN profesori p ON d.id_prof=p.id_prof
           WHERE p.nume=nume;
    END returneaza_id_curs;

    PROCEDURE inserare_nota (nr_matr studenti.nr_matricol%type, nume profesori.nume%type, id_curs note.id_curs%type, valoarea note.valoare%type) IS
    v_id NUMBER(3);
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO note VALUES (nr_matr, id_curs, valoare, NULL);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN id_gresit THEN
        v_id :=returneaza_id_curs(nume);
        IF id_curs <> v_id THEN
           raise_application_error (-20002, 'Profesorul nu preda acest curs');
        END IF;
    END inserare_nota;

END manager_facultate;
/
```

I'm getting this errors when I want to create my package body.

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/16     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "C1" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ( @ % ;
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "C1" to continue.

6/12     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of
         the following:
         not null of nan infinite dangling a empty

6/45     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOIN" when expecting one of
         the following:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
         , ; for group having intersect minus order start union where
         connect
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your function `returneaza_id_curs` is not that clear to me; given that it should be written as `FUNCTION returneaza_id_curs ... IS
    CURSOR c1 (nume NUMBER) IS ...
    BEGIN
        ...           
    END returneaza_id_curs;`, the answer is what should it do; it claims to return a number, but you have no return value, so what should this function do?

Comment: The CURSOR C1 statement should be in the declaration part before BEGIN. You can have a look at this exemple: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/declare.php.

Comment: is it better now
`FUNCTION returneaza_id_curs (nume VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
        CURSOR c1 (nume) IS
           SELECT d.id_curs from didactic d JOIN profesori p ON d.id_prof=p.id_prof
           WHERE p.nume=nume;
        v_id NUMBER(3);
    BEGIN
        open c1;
        LOOP
          fetch c1(nume) into v_id;
          exit when c1%notfound;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN v_id;
    END returneaza_id_curs;`

Answer (score 0):

You should not need a procedure if you have appropriate tables and foreign keys on them:

```
CREATE TABLE People (
  ID         INT PRIMARY KEY,
  First_Name VARCHAR2(100),
  Last_Name  VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Students(
  ID              INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES People( ID ),
  Enrollment_Date DATE
);

CREATE TABLE Staff(
  ID     INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES People( ID ),
  Salary NUMBER,
  Office VARCHAR2(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Courses(
  ID     INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Title  VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Course_Teachers(
  ProfessorID INT REFERENCES Staff( ID ),
  CourseID    INT REFERENCES Courses( ID ),
  Class_Name  VARCHAR2(50),
  PRIMARY KEY ( ProfessorID, CourseID )
);

CREATE TABLE Enrollments(
  ProfessorID INT,
  CourseID    INT,
  StudentID   INT REFERENCES Students ( ID ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( ProfessorID, CourseID ) REFERENCES Course_Teachers ( ProfessorID, CourseID ),
  PRIMARY KEY ( ProfessorID, CourseID, StudentID )
);

CREATE TABLE Assignments(
  ProfessorID      INT REFERENCES Staff( ID ),
  CourseID         INT REFERENCES Courses( ID ),
  AssignmentNumber INT,
  GradePercentage  INT,
  Name             VARCHAR2(50),
  FOREIGN KEY ( ProfessorID, CourseID ) REFERENCES Course_Teachers ( ProfessorID, CourseID ),
  PRIMARY KEY ( ProfessorID, CourseID, AssignmentNumber )
);

CREATE TABLE Grades(
  ProfessorID      INT REFERENCES Staff( ID ),
  CourseID         INT REFERENCES Courses( ID ),
  StudentID        INT REFERENCES Students ( ID ),
  AssignmentNumber INT,
  Grade            INT,
  FOREIGN KEY ( ProfessorID, CourseID, StudentID ) REFERENCES Enrollments ( ProfessorID, CourseID, StudentID ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( ProfessorID, CourseID, AssignmentNumber ) REFERENCES Assignments ( ProfessorID, CourseID, AssignmentNumber ),
  PRIMARY KEY ( ProfessorID, CourseID, StudentID, AssignmentNumber )
);
```